# What is the "proper" way to write out "command line/command-line" in the context of documentation?

Tags: readme

I was proofreading a README file and noticed inconsistent spelling of a phrase spelled two ways: "command line" and "command-line". I went looking for a conclusive answer and did not find much (see [this archived exchange](http://www.techwr-l.com/archives/0711/techwhirl-0711-00735.html) and [this Microsoft style guide page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/a-z-word-list-term-collections/c/command-line)). I concluded that it probably doesn't matter and that "command line" seems to be more common, but now I'm curious; has anyone else run into this issue? If you're an industry professional that documents your code, were you ever provided an answer?

Side note: I was debating whether or not to ask this here, as it's certainly more of a code-adjacent question, but considering that if you're writing code, you *should* be writing documentation as well, I figured it would fit the criteria of "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If this is not the case, do let me know-- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "command line" and "command-line" are acceptable and widely used in today's writing. When used as an adjective before a noun, use "command-line" (with a hyphen) in your writing to help prevent confusion. For example, in the sentence "Make sure you entered the correct command-line parameter." the word "command-line" is describing a type of parameter.

When used as a noun, use "command line" (with no hyphen) in your writing. For example, in the sentence "Open the command line." the use of "command line" is used as a noun.

Comment: Interestingly, I think that's what I was subconsciously doing, but spelling it out (hehe) explicitly like that makes a lot of sense. Language is weird.

Answer (score 1):

`Command line` when using it as a noun: "Type `yo` in the command line."

`Command-line` when using it as a compound adjective: "The command-line usage of this program..."